# Problem with sap.ui.table in same view instantiated in 2 different places

Tags: sapui5

If I use the same view instantiated in 2 different places containing a sap.ui.table, if I modify a column in view A I also see it modified in view B, this problem does not occur with any other type of sap.ui.control,
Can someone help me?

It looks like the aggregation column maintains a global state even if the view is instantiated with different ids in different places.
The problem only occurs when changing the column attributes (visible, width etc.)